# Get access to class variable defined in a module

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec

So while I'm all against extending existing classes this way, sometimes (hacking `rspec`) it's necessary to do something like:

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def define_something(name)
      @@names ||= []
      @@names << name
    end
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  def all_names
    @@names
  end
end
class Example
  include MyModule
  define_something "one"
  define_something "two"
end
Example.new.all_names
```

and then it yields this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@names in MyModule
```

and I understand that because at the time of writing `MyModule::ClassMethods` - we are working on instance not class (not `self.`), so I tried:

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def define_something(name)
      @names ||= []
      @names << name
    end
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  def all_names
    @@names
  end
end
class Example
  include MyModule
  define_something "one"
  define_something "two"
end
Example.new.all_names
```

it does not work either, finally I ended up with:

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def define_something(name)
      @names << name
    end
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_variable_set(:@names, [])
    base.send(:define_method, :all_names) { base.instance_variable_get(:@names) }
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
class Example
  include MyModule
  define_something "one"
  define_something "two"
end
Example.new.all_names
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: `@@` and `@` are completely different. You can never access an `@@` variable using `@`, regardless of whether you're in class or instance context, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually better from a design perspective to avoid crossing the class/instance line using instance variable references. This is usually more clear:

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def define_something(name)
      self.defined_somethings << name
    end

    def defined_somethings
      @_my_module_names ||= []
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def all_names
    self.class.defined_somethings
  end
end

class Example
  include MyModule
  define_something "one"
  define_something "two"
end

Example.new.all_names.inspect
#=> ["one","two"]
```

I've taken care here to create a class-level instance variable with a verbose name. Calling it `@name` could put it into conflict with a variable defined by the class that includes this module. Remember, when designing mixin code you're a guest and you need to be extra polite.

Class-type instance variables like `@@name` are sometimes trouble because they can end up spanning inheritance chains depending on how they're used. Defining a method means you can override it at any point in the chain, something not possible with a shared variable.

In other words, treat the instance's class as a separate object and make clear, well-defined method calls to maintain that separation.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def define_something(name)
      @names ||= []
      @names << name
    end
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  def all_names
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@names)
  end
end
class Example
  include MyModule
  define_something "one"
  define_something "two"
end

Example.new.all_names
```

A class variable can be accessed using `@@` operator from a class level method i.e. `self.` methods.

@tadman's answer has a generic approach for similar problems (generally found in gems that provide modules to implement a functionality)